# How to auto-saved address of user?

Tags: android

Currently I have an EditText field which requires user to input their address. First time user has to input the address. How do I auto complete it when the same user use the app again ?

Answer (score 0):

Use `SharedPreferences`. Here is [a complete example](http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/android/core/content/android-sharedpreferences-example/)

Answer (score 0):

Use [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html)

Call this to save:

```
SharedPreferences.Editor prefsEditor = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
prefsEditor.putString("address", address.getText().toString());
prefsEditor.apply();
```

Call this to load:

```
SharedPreferences mPrefs = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
address.setText(mPrefs.getString("address", ""));
```

Your going to want to add some further code to this such as:

- Null checks